# How to get the user's group(s) for sharepoint online site usig Microsoft Graph APIs

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, groups, microsoft-graph

I am trying to get the user's group(s) for SharePoint online site using Microsoft Graph APIs. But I am not getting any equivalent graph API for the below SharePoint rest API :

```
/_api/web/SiteUsers/GetByEmail('xxxxx@xxxxx.com')?$expand=Groups
```

I want the SharePoint groups not the AD groups. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Graph APIs **does not support** SharePoint groups yet.

---

**Additional**:

You can check below threads where others are suggesting to query "User Information List" to get the SharePoint site permissions (Which might not work for your case as you need groups of specific user):

1. [Get SharePoint Groups (not AD groups) using Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50505910/get-sharepoint-groups-not-ad-groups-using-graph-api)
2. [How to get SharePoint site group name using Graph API?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/135386/how-to-get-sharepoint-site-group-name-using-graph.html)

Comment: Thanks @Ganesh, I have tried the above ways, but those are giving me the User Information List, but not the user's group (to which it is belogs from SPO site).

Comment: That's what I thought & mentioned in my answer. Long story short, Microsoft Graph APIs does not support working with SharePoint groups of a user.